# Run interactively with existing docker container

Tags: docker

I have a container started as the following:

```
docker run --interactive --tty --gpus all --name my_container 
--workdir "/home/ubuntu" --user ubuntu 
--volume /hdd/all_cv/paiv/metis:/home/ubuntu/my --publish 8888:8888 my
```

how do I run interactively with `my_container` once I reboot my machine?

Comment: `docker run` a new container in parallel to the existing one, or `docker exec` a debugging shell, are the usual approaches; have you tried either of these?

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried `docker run`, it won't allow me to start a new container with the same name, so what I need to do is actually to use the existing one (and I hope to use it interactively). So the question is how to achieve that with existing docker?

Comment: Why does it need to have the same name?  Is your issue just that you lose the interactive shell when your system reboots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/), you can attach back to the detached container using `docker attach` command:

> Use `docker attach` to attach your terminal’s standard input, output, and error (or any combination of the three) to a running container using the container’s ID or name. This allows you to view its ongoing output or to control it interactively, as though the commands were running directly in your terminal.

So you should try this to have an interactive session with your already running container:

```sh
docker attach my_container
```

Answer (score 1):

If your container is stopped, you just need to start it again

```
docker ps -aq -f name=my_container | xargs docker start $1
```